# HostingEnvironment.MapPath returning null in .net Project

Tags: c#, .net

```
  string File = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Doc/Test.csv");
```

The problem is that HostingEnvironment.MapPath is returning null.

Comment: Are you using Asp.net MVC?

Comment: NO Not ASP.NET  MVC

Comment: Which one you are using? so that we can help you.

Comment: In winform project using c#

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath` for Winforms applications.

You can use `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()` for this purpose. It works similarly to `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath`

Here is how you can do this.

```
string File = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("\Doc\Test.csv");
```

For more information please see [Path.GetFullPath Reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.7.2)